# Error when scan from file. Error on print out

Tags: java, file

There is an error in the printout of the maze and navigation, I believe it is when i Scan from the file but I could be wrong.

FILE INPUT

```
5 5
P.XX.
.X...
...X.
XXT..
..X..
```

Sample of what I see

```
P P P P P 
X X X X X 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 

You may:
1) Move up
2) Move down
3) Move left
4) Move right
0) Quit
```

What I should see

```
P.XX.
.X...
...X.
XXT..
..X..

You may:
1) Move up
2) Move down
3) Move left
4) Move right
0) Quit
```

CODE

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
public class MazeGame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"));
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
int rows = scan.nextInt();
int columns = scan.nextInt();
int px = 0;
int py = 0;
String [][] maze = new String[rows][columns];
//String junk = scan.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    String temp = scan.nextLine();
    String[] arrayPasser = temp.split("");
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        maze[i][j] = arrayPasser[i];
    }
}

boolean gotTreasure = false;

while (gotTreasure == false){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.print("\n");
  }


    System.out.printf("\n");
    System.out.println("You may:");
    System.out.println("1) Move up");
    System.out.println("2) Move down");
    System.out.println("3) Move left");
    System.out.println("4) Move right");
    System.out.println("0) Quit");
    int choice = user.nextInt();
    int i = 0;

    if (choice == 1 && i >= 0 && i < columns){
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < columns; l++){
                if (maze[k][l].equals(maze[px][py]) && maze[px][py-1].equals("X") == false){
                    maze[px][py] = ".";
                    maze[k][l-1] = "P";
                    maze[px][py] = maze[k][l-1];
                }else if (maze[px][py-1] == "X"){
                    System.out.println("Cannot move into a cave-in! Try something else.");
                }else {
                continue;}


                }
            }
        }
    else if (choice == 2 && i >= 0 && i < columns){
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < columns; l++){
                if (maze[k][l].equals(maze[px][py]) && maze[px][py+1].equals("X") == false){
                    maze[px][py] = ".";
                    maze[k][l+1] = "P";
                    maze[px][py] = maze[k][l+1];
                }else if (maze[px][py+1] == "X"){
                    System.out.println("Cannot move into a cave-in! Try something else.");
                }else {
                continue;}

           }
         }
        }
    else if (choice == 3 && i >= 0 && i < columns){
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < columns; l++){
                if (maze[k][l].equals(maze[px][py]) && maze[px-1][py].equals("X") == false){
                    maze[px][py] = ".";
                    maze[k-1][l] = "P";
                    maze[px][py] = maze[k-1][l];
                }else if (maze[px-1][py] == "X"){
                    System.out.println("Cannot move into a cave-in! Try something else.");
                }else {
                continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 4 && i >= 0 && i < columns){
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < columns; l++){
                if (maze[k][l].equals(maze[px][py]) && maze[px+1][py].equals("X") == false){
                    maze[px][py] = ".";
                    maze[k+1][l] = "P";
                    maze[px][py] = maze[k+1][l];
                }else if (maze[px+1][py] == "X"){
                    System.out.println("Cannot move into a cave-in! Try something else.");
                }else {
                continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 0){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

System.out.println("Congratulations, you found the treasure!");

scan.close();
user.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Any specific reason `maze` is an `String[][]`, not a `char[][]`? The latter is more intuitive and will make your life easier with things like: `maze[i] = scan.nextLine().toCharArray();`.

Comment: @Dukeling You should make that an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @WilliamGaul Yeah, but it's not really an answer. Typically the main part of an answer should address the problem directly. As an additional note one can mention a better way of doing things.

Comment: @Dukeling Ah I guess so. Still, its a very nice piece of code. And one I would have loved to use when I did an assignment like this before :P

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
maze[i][j] = arrayPasser[i];
```

should be:

```
maze[i][j] = arrayPasser[j];
```

The reason is, `i` remains constant while you are copying from `arrayPasser` to `maze`, so you're going to get an entire row of the same character, namely the one at `(i, i)`.

Comment: I had that but it was giving me an error out of bounds exception.        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at MazeGame.main(MazeGame.java:19)

Comment: The line that is with the arrayPasser which was fixed above. But the fix caused the new error. I guess I was wondering what is wrong with the code now that that line is fixed? Is the array or arrayPasser's logic off when it tries to execute this line of code? What part is causing this error to happen? thanks...

Comment: The size of your `maze` is declared correctly so I don't think it's that. Try to debug by `System.out.println()` both `temp` and `arrayPasser` and seeing what they look like. Or if you have a debugger use that. My guess is that for some reason the scanner is not reading in the maze right.

Comment: The scan is working because the Temp is correct on the maze. It has to be something with the arrayPass

Comment: Okay so when you print out `arrayPasser` what does it look like?

Comment: Found the error. I have the line of code commented out that eats the line before that code. Thanks for the help! Now I have to solve why the movement is not working....

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same homework problem.

But instead of having the 2D array be a string, I have it as a 2D char array. (thus not much change beyond a few key words) and it works perfectly fine...as far as reading and printing the initial "puzzle".

```
// Create maze in 2 dimensional character array.
    char[][] maze = new char[R][C];
    input1.nextLine();

    // Scan maze.
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        String row = input1.next();
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            maze[i][j] = row.charAt(j);
    }
// Print Maze. (in your while loop)
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```

give that a try.